# How to avoid some custom views freezing the UI thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, view, program-entry-point, freeze

I have 9 custom views (extending the View class each of them) in one of my game window that are causing a freeze in my UI thread, when I press the "Play" button, the app freezes (when inflating the layout in "onCreateView", i'm using Fragments) until the game window is generated, something very very ugly.

I'm trying to do this in a separate thread but all are problems, Android doesn't allow me to create new views out of the main (UI) thread.

I tried so many things but I can't get it, could anyone tell me how to achieve this?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

For very cpu intensive drawing you can use.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html

> One of the purposes of this class is to provide a surface in which a
>   secondary thread can render into the screen.

Comment: Thank you Dominik, but the problem isn't during the game. The problem is in the transition between the "Play window" and the "Game window", the app freezes while it generates the "Game window" when I press the "Play" button. When the "Game window" is loaded all works as expected. And the freeze happens because having the 9 custom views in the layout xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by manually inflating the layout in an AsyncTask. I call the AsyncTask from the "Play Window" where I show a "loading" view and in "onPostExecute" I create the "Game Window" (Fragment) and replace it.

Some dummy code (PlayFragment is the previous screen of GameFragment):

"Play button click" (PlayFragment):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_play:
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable(ARG_SELECTED_GAME, selectedGame);
            rlLoadingGame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            GameFragment gameFragment = GameFragment.newInstance(selectedGame);
            gameFragment.loadGame(activity, bundle);
            break;
    }
}
```

loadGame method (GameFragment):

```
public void loadGame(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
    this.activity = activity;
    if (bundle != null) {
        currentGame = (Game) bundle.getSerializable(ARG_SELECTED_GAME);
    }
    new GenerateGame(bundle).execute();
}
```

GenerateGame AsyncTask (GameFragment):

```
class GenerateGame extends AsyncTask<Void, Void>, View> {
    private Bundle bundle;

    public GenerateGame(Bundle bundle) {
        this.bundle = bundle;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // do your stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected View doInBackground(Void... params) {
        View child = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.game_fragment_layout, null);
        // do all your heavy load stuff
        return child;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(View layout) {
        super.onPostExecute(layout);
        // initialize and set all UI elements
        replaceFragment(layout, bundle);
    }
}
```

replaceFragment method (GameFragment):

```
private void replaceFragment(View newView, Bundle bundle) {
    fragmentLayout = newView;
    // call to fragment manager replace/add or required method passing this as Fragment to replace and the bundle if needed
}
```

onCreateView (GameFragment):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (fragmentLayout != null) {
        return fragmentLayout;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the first approach so it can be refactored and so many things can be done in a better way but it is up to you.